# Closure of union of locally finite collection of subsets equal to union of closures.

Tags: general-topology

Say $\mathcal{S}=\{S_i|i\in I\}$ is a locally finite collection of subsets of a topological space $X$. Then
$$\overline{\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i} = \bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}.$$

I don't see why this is true.. Hope someone can explain it to me!

Comment: In the next time, try to explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 10):

For the "trivial" inclusion: note that for every $i\in I$ you have $S_i\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ so $\overline{S_i}\subseteq\overline{\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i}$. Taking the union on the left side, we have $\bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}\subseteq\overline{\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i}$.

For the converse, it is enough to prove that $\bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}$ is closed. (This is because it trivially contains $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$, so it must then contain its closure (i.e. $\overline{\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i}$).)

For that purpose, pick $x\not\in \bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}$. Due to local finiteness, there is an neigbourhood / open set $U, x\in U$ such that $U$ intersects only finitely many $S_i$'s: let's say $S_{i_1}, S_{i_2},\ldots,S_{i_n}$. Now create a new neighbourhood $U'=U\setminus(\overline{S_{i_1}}\cup\overline{S_{i_2}}\cup\cdots\cup\overline{S_{i_n}})$. It is an open set, it still contains $x$, and it does not intersect any of $S_i$'s, which implies (as it is open) that it also does not intersect any of $\overline{S_i}$'s.

Thus, the complement of $\bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}$ is open, i.e. $\bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}$ is closed.

Comment: how is $U'$ open

Comment: @Uncool It is the difference between an open set and a closed set.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $x$ belongs to the closure of $S=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$. Fix a neighborhood $U_0$ of $X$, so $U_0\cap S\ne\emptyset$. On the other hand, $U_0$ can be chosen to only intersect a finite number of the $S_i$, say $S_{i_1},\dots,S_{i_n}$. Any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U\subseteq U_0$, must intersect $S$, so
$$
U\cap (S_{i_1}\cup\dots\cup S_{i_n})\ne\emptyset
$$
because
$$
U\cap\biggl(\,\bigcup_{i\in I\setminus\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}}S_i\biggr)=\emptyset
$$
In particular, since the neighborhoods of $x$ contained in $U_0$ form a base,
$$
x\in\overline{S_{i_1}\cup\dots\cup S_{i_n}}=
\overline{S_{i_1}}\cup\dots\cup \overline{S_{i_n}}\subseteq
\bigcup_{i\in I}\overline{S_i}
$$
The converse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: I was trying to prove to myself that $U_0$ must intersect a finite number of $S_i$, and could not. Why must this be true? In particular, suppose $x \in \overline{S} \setminus S$.

Comment: @user20672 $\mathcal{S}$ is supposed to be a locally finite family.

Comment: @user20672 I should have written that $U_0$ can be chosen to intersect only a finite number of members of $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Why do neighbourhoods of $x$ contained in $U_{0}$ form a base for topology on $X$?

Comment: @P-addict They form a basis of neighborhoods for $x$. Indeed, if $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then $V\cap U_0$ is a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U_0$ (and in $V$; the family is obviously closed under intersections.

Comment: Oh right, I thought these neighbourhoods were forming a base for whole X. Thanks a lot for clarifying

Comment: Hi egreg. Why can we infer that $U\cap (S_{i_1}\cup\dots\cup S_{i_n})\ne\emptyset$ from $U\cap\biggl(\,\bigcup_{i\in I\setminus\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}}S_i\biggr)=\emptyset$ and $U_0\cap S\ne\emptyset$ and $U\subseteq U_0$? I feel like that $U\cap S=\emptyset$ can be true for some $U$ as well. And if so, we should have that $U\cap (S_{i_1}\cup\dots\cup S_{i_n})= \emptyset$. Thanks.

Comment: @SamWong We know that $U$ *must* intersect $S=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$, because it's a neighborhood of $x$ which is in the closure of the union of $S$. On the other hand, $U\subseteq U_0$, which only intersects (nonvacuously) $S_{i_1},\dots,S_{i_n}$. So the points in $U\cap S$ must belong to $S_{i_1}\cup\dots\cup S_{i_n}$ and $U\cap S_i=\emptyset$ if $i\notin\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$.

Comment: @egreg You are right. I forgot that $x$ was a limit point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*This is a partial solution that works in spaces where closure coincides with sequential closure, such as Frechet spaces.*

Pick $$x\in \overline{\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i}$$

Then because $\mathcal{S}$ is locally finite there is a neighbourhood $x\in U$ such that $U$ has a non-empty intersection with only finitely many $S_i$'s.

Now pick a sequence $x_k\in \bigcup_{i\in I} S_i$ that converges to $x$. You can choose the $x_k$ to lie in $U$ because it is a neighbourhood of $x$ (or in any case they will all lie in $U$ except finitely many of them).

Since there are infinitely many $x_k$ but finitely many $S_i$ where they can possibly lie, by the pigeonhole principle, there is a subsequence that lies entirely in one and the same $S_i$. It follows that $x$ lies in the closure of that particular $S_i$.

Therefore we have proved $$\overline{\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i}\subset \bigcup_{i\in I} \overline{S_i}$$

The other direction is trivial.