# Help with proof of Lemma 1 in "A note on paracompact spaces" (Michael, PAMS 4 (5), 1953)

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, separation-axioms, paracompactness

In the [paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/2032419) by Ernest Michael cited in the title of this question, the following Lemma is crucial, but a step in the proof confuses me.

**Lemma 1.** Let $X$ be a regular space. Then the following are equivalent:

1. Every open covering of $X$ has an open locally finite refinement, i.e. $X$ is paracompact.
2. Every open covering of $X$ has a locally finite refinement.
3. Every open covering of $X$ has a closed locally finite refinement.

Here is the proof given for (3) $\implies$ (1), copied mostly verbatim, with one annotation of the form [?!] for reference below.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{R}$ be an open covering of $X$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a locally finite refinement of $\mathcal{R}$, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a covering of $X$ by open sets, each of which intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal{A}$. Now let $\mathcal{W}$ be a closed, locally finite refinement of $\mathcal{B}$. For each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, let $A' = X \setminus \bigcup \{ W \in \mathcal{W} \, | \, A \cap W = \emptyset \}$; then $A'$ is an open set [?!] containing $A$, and if $W \in \mathcal{W}$, then $W$ intersects $A'$ if and only if $W$ intersects $A$. For each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, pick an $R_A \in \mathcal{R}$ such that $A \subset R_A$. Let $\mathcal{U} = \{ A' \cap R_A \, | \, A \in \mathcal{A} \}$. Then $\mathcal{U}$ is an open refinement of $\mathcal{R}$, and since each element of the locally finite covering $\mathcal{W}$ intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{U}$ is locally finite. $\square$

*Discussion.* Let $\mathcal{W}_A := \{ W \in \mathcal{W} \, | \, A \cap W = \emptyset \}$. This is a family of closed sets. As [?!] indicates, I don't see why $A' = X \setminus \bigcup \mathcal{W}_A$ is open, or equivalently why $\bigcup \mathcal{W}_A$ is closed. My confusion is that, in general, $\mathcal{W}_A$ is infinite. Indeed, note that the family of open sets $\mathcal{B}_A := \{ B \in \mathcal{B} \, | \, A \cap B = \emptyset \}$ is cofinite in $\mathcal{B}$ by assumption. If we choose a map $b: \mathcal{W} \to \mathcal{B}$ such that $W \subseteq b(W)$ for each $W \in \mathcal{W}$, then $b^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_A) \subseteq \mathcal{W}_A$, so $\mathcal{W}_A$ is infinite for every $A$ whenever $\mathcal{B}$ is infinite. But then I don't see why the union $\bigcup \mathcal{W}_A$ should be closed, since in general an infinite union of closed sets is not closed.

My first thought is to define $\mathcal{B}'_A := \{ b(W) \, | \, W \in \mathcal{W}, \, W \cap A = \emptyset   \}$ (keeping the chosen map $b$ from the previous paragraph), then instead of $A'$ use $A'' := X \setminus \bigcup \mathcal{B}'_A$. Since each $b(W)$ is open, $A''$ is certainly closed, but now it's not at all clear that $A''$ contains $A$, since $b(W)$ can intersect $A$ even when $W$ does not. So this first thought is not quite right.

Stepping outside the (compact) text into the para(compact)text,   I don't actually think that there is an error, because if there was one, someone would have caught it by now. (In particular, Jean Dieudonné wrote the review that is now in MathSciNet, and I trust his understanding rather more than my own.) Any indication of where I failed to understand the proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't  (3) $\implies$ (2) trivial? Do you mean  (3) $\implies$ (1)?

Comment: @PaulFrost thanks, fixed.

Comment: I have a slightly different write-up of the lemma [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/03.pdf), it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the family $\mathcal{W}_A$ may be infinite. But it is a *locally finite* family of closed sets and thus the union of its members is closed. See [here](https://planetmath.org/theunionofalocallyfinitecollectionofclosedsetsisclosed) or [Closure of union of locally finite collection of subsets equal to union of closures.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2623619)

Comment: A thousand sheafy thank-you's!

Comment: @SophieMacDonald sheafy?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma not genuinely sheafy, I just got excited. The PlanetMath link that Paul gave ("here", in his final sentence) links to an observation about gluing together continuous functions defined on various sets in a family to get a continuous function on the union. You can do this with any old family of open sets (this was the sheafy bit); the observation was that you can also do it with closed sets if the family is locally finite. I have played with the very basics of sheaves before, because they sounded cool, but it was neat to see gluing come up in something I was already trying to do.